# Play flash content in QuickTime player

Tags: display, quicktime, adobe-flash

It possible play web video content like a Flash or HTML5 file in external player like a QuickTime player or VLC player.

Play video like it made in iphone when using safari.

Comment: What web video content in particular do you want to be able to play? Like, what website are you thinking about?

Comment: all stuff in internet. for example: i'm watching tv on website and better look  channel in player then on website. TV content on website is flash content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time ago I used the "Elmedia Player" for playing old flash movies I had on my disk. Don't know how it works nowadays, but they have a free version to try.

http://mac.eltima.com/media-player.html

Comment: Not tested yet. it required osx 10.7.mine is 10.6.8 still but it's looks like what finding.